# C# wpf несколько combobox'ов привязаных к одной коллекции, как скрыть выбраные item?

Tags: c#, wpf

Добрый вечер, прошерстил форумы, но ни где не попалось, как скрыть выделенные item combobox'ов. Задача такая: есть коллекция объектов, и несколько combobox'ов, которые все привязаны к этой коллеции, нужно что бы при выборе одного item'a, он убирался из других combobox'ов. Кто может натолкнуть в какую сторону копать?

Объекты коллекции:

```
public class LinkedItem  
{
    public int ColumnId { get; set; } // Уникальный ID
    public string ColumnName { get; set; } // Имя отображаемое в combobox
    public string ColumnLink { get; set; } // Значение, которое передает определенный combobox
    public bool isNoSelected { get; set; } // Выделялся ли ранее этот объект?
}
```

Comment: Никак. Придется использовать несколько коллекций.

Comment: Добавьте дополнительный индекс в свойства item'а и игнорируйте при обновлении combobox если не равен `-1` (не выбран никем) или отличен от текущего. Только вам придётся заново переопределять список item'ом для каждого combobox'а при наличии ивента выбора в любом из них. `isNoSelected` выкиньте.

Comment: Двухсторонняя привязка combobox и коллекции, попробуй по крайней мере